# Django import error -- No module named core.management

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run `python manage.py` on a Django app and I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
Brocks-Mac-mini:firstdjango BrockMorrison$
```

I have Django installed on my system. Using `pip freeze | grep -i django` I get the following:

```
Django==1.11.1
```

When I search for the path that Django is installed it gives me:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I have tried updating to the latest version of Django and when I try running `pip install django` in the folder it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied. I have tried looking on other stack overflow posts, but none of the other solutions have helped me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the results from running `which python` and `which pip`? Then try opening a python shell with `python` and do `import django` and tell us what you get.

Comment: Do you have a folder called django in the same folder as your project?
Are you using a virtualenv? did you maybe forget to source it?

Comment: @Ouss No, there is no folder in my project folder named django. I am not using a virtualenv. All I did was set up a new project and try to run the `python manage.py runserver` command and it gives me the error in question.

Comment: @FrankT `which python` yields `/usr/bin/python` and `which pip` yields `/usr/local/bin/pip`. When I run a python shell and I try to import Django it gives me `ImportError: No module named django`.

Comment: Then it must be the packages path... Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is most common when django isn't found in the current python environment.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with your `PYTHONPATH` not being properly set to use the local python lib you have.  I've seen this before on osx.  Try to fix with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

You should be able to just add that to your `.bashrc` or on `osx` you're probably using `zsh` so add to bottom of your `.zshrc`.  But I really recommend setting up `pyenv` over this fix as it is a much cleaner way of dealing with multiple python environments and projects going forward.

So, the `pyenv` solution is to setup `pyenv` https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv, install python version you want, create a virtualenv with it, activate the virtualenv, pip install django.